# Did I contradict this correctly?

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

The question is as follows:

Let $A,B \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be connected subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $A\cap B \neq \emptyset$. Prove $A\cup B$ is connected.

I haven't done contradiction proofs in quite some time, but I just want to correctly contradict this statement. Is this the correct contradiction statement:
$A,B \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ are separate subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $A \cup B = \emptyset$. Do I also have to contradict what I am trying to prove, or is the goal to still show that $A\cup B$ is connected, or is what I have done wrong?

Comment: Proof by contradiction generally involves assuming that the conclusion is false. In this case you would assume that $A \cup B$ are not connected and then hope to find a contradiction by seeing that invalidates the previous assumptions (e.g. That $A,B$ are not connected subsets or that $A \cap B$ is is empty, etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An implication $(P \implies Q)$ is equivalent to $(\neg P \lor Q)$. Negating this statement will give $(P\land \neg Q)$. If $(P\land \neg Q)$ is false then its negation $(P\implies Q)$ is true.

You should therefore assume that $A,B\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n}$ are connected subsets of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and their intersection is non-empty, as well as, $A \cup B$ is not connected.

Comment: This helps a lot, thank you! I gotta brush up on my skills in that area